How to extract hyperlinks attached to script?
Given
inventory={
{"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506", {"plant protection", "land plot", "agricultural production"}},
{"https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672", {"environmental protection", "land plot"}}
};

I want to link the set of tags, for example, {"plant protection", "land plot", "agricultural production"} to the associated URL link https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506 and filter the inventory using the tags to retrieve the associated URL links?
Example: when I filter the inventory using the tag land plot, I should get both URL links in the inventory list because land plot is common among the URL links.

Edit 1: Added url hyperlinks
inventory={
  {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506", {"plant protection", "land plot", "agricultural production"}},
  {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672", {"environmental protection", "land plot"}}};

ds = Query[All, {"url" -> URL}]@
       Dataset[AssociationThread[{"url", "tags"} -> #] & /@ inventory]

lookup[words__] :=
 Query[
   Select[
    Or @@ 
      Map[word |-> StringContainsQ[StringRiffle[#tags, "|"], word], words] &]
   , {"url", "tags"}]@ds

words = {"prot", "agri"};
lookup[words] [All, "url"] // Normal


{URL["https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506"],  URL["https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672"]}

words = {"envi"};
lookup[words] [All, "url"] // Normal


{URL["https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672"]}


Outputs from your code, URL links, should be clickable so that I can just click on it and go to the actual document. URLs in ds should also be clickable.

@TugrulTemel Thank you for the accepted answer. Please take a look at the updated version.

You haven't provided much detail about the actual structure of the things you want to work with, but here's a stab at a solution. This creates an association that maps tags to urls. You can just query this association.
urlsByTag = Merge[Thread@*Apply[Rule]@*Reverse /@ inventory, Identity]
(* <|"plant protection" -> {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506"}, 
     "land plot" -> {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506", "https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672"}, 
     "agricultural production" -> {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506"}, 
     "environmental protection" -> {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672"}|> *)

urlsByTag["plant protection"]
(* {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506"} *)

urlsByTag["land plot"]
(* {"https://lex.uz/en/docs/3815506", "https://lex.uz/en/docs/6906672"} *)


Actually, I have a total of 40,000 URL links and each one has a few tags to be attached like you did. My ultimate goal is to use a selected number of tags at once to retrieve the associated set of URL links. From there on, I will go into each one of the URL links to assess using some criteria. Is there a way to use a single word tag like land to retrieve the links, tags of which have multiple words like land plot? In a way, I shorten the two-word tag to a single word. Often, I need to collect the links with a single word tag while the actual tags have two words.
